# Issue with an “invalid issuer or signature” response from Sharepoint Online via Salesforce Apex REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to make REST callouts from Salesforce to Sharepoint and I'm getting an "Invalid issuer or signature" response from my code. I tried generating a self-signed certificate on Salesforce and uploading the .crt file in my Sharepoint app, but the same error message still persists. Is there something I'm missing here?

Something else I don't understand is that when I upload the Salesforce certificate using the "Upload Public Key", I get a Private Key type generated for that public cert with a private key number. Maybe this a mislabeling on the App Registration Portal itself?

Salesforce Apex REST code:

```
public class AuthCallout {
   public static void basicAuthCallout(){
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setMethod('GET');
     req.setEndpoint('callout:Sharepoint_Online/_api/web/list');
}
}
```

The Sharepoint_Online Named Credential uses the self-signed certificate and Oauth2.0 with the "Files.Read.All Sites.Read.All offline_access" scope. The authentication status says Authenticated, so I know that part is fine. From SF, I downloaded the public .crt file and reuploaded it to my registered app in "apps.dev.microsoft.com".

Comment: Maybe you haven't set the correct permissions in the SharePoint App... Anyways, you should give more information when you create a question. Is hard to help with that info

Comment: I gave Files.Read.All and Sites.Read.All permissions for the app. What more information are you looking for? I followed the steps for 'offline_access' too and those are properly referenced in the Salesforce scopes. Microsoft isn't terribly verbose in their REST API errors, so it's hard for me to pinpoint the issue myself.

Comment: How you made your app, wich steps you followed... code... things you think it can help. The call to the API...
I am not pretty sure where you are adding those permissions, but at least in azure Portal, after adding permissions, there is a button at top that says something like "Grant permissions". Maybe you missed that

Comment: Done. I added these permissions via the app I registered in the Application Registration Portal under "Application Permissions" and "Delegated Permissions"

Comment: Fine! add the answer and mark it as correct or I do, so it appears as resolved question :)

Comment: Well Mikel, adding the permissions didn't resolve the error message I am still receiving. I said "Done" as in it was already done prior to me posting this issue. I still get the same error message regardless and Microsoft Online is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my Named Credential URL to point to Microsoft Graph and then my Sharepoint Tenant now gives me a 'Bad Request' "Inner Error", so it appears to have worked in getting me inside Sharepoint Online.